# Gmail Action sending mail from AppScript

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to include the inbox gmail action in a mail sent from an google appscript.
I log the entire body before send the mail. 
This is the html

```
<html>
   <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
       <meta itemprop="description" content="Approvazione richiesta da Intranet Noovle"/>
       <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ConfirmAction">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Accetta"/>
          <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
             <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.google.com"/>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>
  <p>Gentile  
     Mr X,
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...
  </p>
  ...
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

If I try to send this email from a Google AppScript, without whitelisting the address but sending the mail to the sender, the button isn't displayed.

But if I try to use the Google Validator (https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/testing-your-schema),it validates the action gmail schema and then tryies to send a real mail to the current google account logged (from the same account, like I did in the app script)

And the mail come right with the action!

Are there any App script limits?

Answer (score 0):

Emails with markup need to be signed with DKIM/SPF for the actions to be rendered. Are you using a Gmail account or a Google Apps account? With the latter, if DKIM is properly configured for the domain, you should get a valid signature.

Comment: Yes I'm a Google Apps user. I know the signature but I read that if recipient is same than sender, you don't need the signature.

I'm sure about this because I tryed this with an AppEngine app in Java and the same Apps domain

Comment: Test emails sent to yourself must be signed too, otherwise anyone could spoof your email address and send you unwanted actions.